# Excel VBA - Creating a new Workbook without it being added to the jumplist

Tags: excel, vba

Is the a way to create a new workbook without the file name being added to the jumplist for excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the entry for the workbook from the `RecentFiles` collection, like this:

```
Dim r As RecentFile
Dim wb As Workbook

' Change this to point to the workbook to be removed from the jump list
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each r In Application.RecentFiles
    If r.Path = wb.FullName Then
        r.Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next r
```